# how to load different xibs in iphone and ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I wanna at certain point of the program to load different xib for iphone and for ipad but wanna to reuse most part of the code. how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append `~ipad` or `~iphone` to the end of the file name. So `SomeViewController~ipad.xib` or `SomeViewController~iphone.xib` for instance.

See [iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you create a template project that is universal you can inspect the code created for that version.  For Example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
      MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
      self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
      self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
  } else { // iPad
      MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
      UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

      PSGameViewController *detailViewController = [[PSGameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
      UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

      self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
      self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
      self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

      self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
  }

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

or from `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
  if (self.detailViewController == nil) {
      self.detailViewController = [[PSGameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PSGameViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
  }

  self.detailViewController.model = selectedModel;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
  self.pushedIndexPath = indexPath;


} else { // iPad

  self.detailViewController.model = selectedModel;
}
```